# Java SimpleDateFormat interpret parse-string as UTC

Tags: java, date

my timezone is GMT+1.

so a "Date"-object with "22.09.1985 00:00UTC" prints "Sun Sep 22 01:00:00 CEST 1985" on the tostring function.

Now i'm trying to create this date by parsing "22/09/1985" with simpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date d = sdf.parse("22/09/1985");
    => Sun Sep 22 00:00:00 CEST 1985

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date d = sdf.parse("22/09/1985");
    => Sun Sep 22 02:00:00 CEST 1985
```

how can i configure simpledateformat that it creates an Date which prints "Sun Sep 22 01:00:00 CEST 1985" with input string "22/09/1985"?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z dd/MM/YYYY");`

Comment: so it is impossible to let sdf interpret a string as UTC without defining the timezone in the string??

Comment: Strictly speaking, all `Date` objects are based on UTC since it's internally stored as the number of milliseconds since 1970-Jan-01 00:00 UTC.  Use a second `DateFormat` to display the actual text of the date in the correct timezone.

Comment: you didn't get me: i know that "Date" has no timezone ... but how can i parse a date without respecting any timezone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My assumption was wrong,

```
22.09.1985 00:00UTC is actually 22.09.1985 02:00CET
```

so

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date d = sdf.parse("22/09/1985");
```

is exactly what i wanted, the date i compared it with was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

## Avoid java.util.Date & Calendar

You’ve found one of the many reasons to avoid using java.util.Date & .Calendar. They are notoriously troublesome. Either use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or, in Java 8, the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which is inspired by Joda-Time and defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Search StackOverflow for "joda date" to find many examples.

## Time Zone

You said:

> my timezone is GMT+1.

Incorrect, your local *offset* from UTC/GMT is +01. That is not your time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* rules about Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies.

And that offset should have two digits: `+01` (or `+01:00`) rather than `+1`, according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) standard.

Avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes such as CET. They are neither standardized nor unique. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Generally speaking, you should specify a time zone in all your date-time work rather than rely on the current JVM's default.

In both Joda-Time and java.time, a date-time object truly knows its assigned time zone. A java.util.Date has no time zone, but seems to because its `toString` applies the default time zone when creating a String representation, as you sadly learned the hard way.

## Example Code

Some code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
String input = "22/09/1985";

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Amsterdam" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( input );
DateTime dateTimeUtcGmt = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
String outputMontreal = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).print( dateTime );
// All of the above date-time represent the very same moment in the timeline of the Universe.
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtcGmt: " + dateTimeUtcGmt );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
System.out.println( "outputMontreal: " + outputMontreal );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 1985-09-22T00:00:00.000+02:00
dateTimeUtcGmt: 1985-09-21T22:00:00.000Z
dateTimeIndia: 1985-09-22T03:30:00.000+05:30
outputMontreal: samedi 21 septembre 1985 18 h 00 EDT
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're parsing a date string, using a specific time zone, doesn't make the printed `Date` object to use that time zone. You're still using the same implementation of `Date#toString()`, which formats the `Date` object using the default timezone.

What you would need is to `format` your `Date` object with that `SimpleDateFormat` object. And if you have that specific string, then you would need another `SimpleDateFormat` object for parsing that string:

```
String dateString = "22/09/1985";

SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date parsedDate = parser.parse(dateString);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(parsedDate));
```

Java `Date` doesn't have the concept of TimeZone associated with it. You can only format a `Date` object using a specified timezone, and get a string. Or else, switch to [JodaTime library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: the date object still has the value "Sun Sep 22 00:00:00 CEST 1985" which is not what i want

Comment: @wutzebaer Date object doesn't have the concept of TimeZone. You can only format it to a date string wrt to a specific timezone. I would suggest you to look into JodaTime library, which is much better when dealing with dates.

Comment: @RohitJain It's always bugged me that the stock JDK libs don't have any `Calendar` formatting classes since `Calendar` is meant to be used when time zones do matter.

Comment: @Powerlord Exactly, and it's a headache to get a `Calendar` instance for a particular Date. This is worst part of the Java API.

Comment: @Powerlord So, waiting for another Maven compile eh? ;)

Comment: @RohitJain Well, no, actually I'm about to leave for lunch and had a few minutes to kill... although you just reminded me I haven't recompiled since my last changes so I should be doing a Maven compile now!

Comment: @Powerlord haha :) Can I suggest you to schedule maven compile, to let you free of that task? Just kidding ;)

Comment: i know that date han't any timezone... but why is it so hard to parse a string to a date without respecting any timezone?

Comment: @wutzebaer B'coz that is how Java's `Date` API has been designed, and you've to live with it, till Java 8 comes with its new improved DateTime API, based on Joda Time only.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is a relatively "dumb" class, as it just represents the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

If you want to print out a Date as if it were a different timezone, you need to construct a `DateFormat` / `SimpleDateFormat` for that `TimeZone` and [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) it to a String that way.