# Java simpleDateFormat does not parse date correctly for given Locale?

Tags: java, android, timezone, simpledateformat

Here in my code I get the current time and than format it according to "UTC" timezone and than parsed it using the same Timezone hence converting it to a Date. The problem is that I get the date as "Wed Jul 20 13:04:51 GMT+05:00 2016" than
its formatted and parse as in the code below

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();
    //gives time as "Wed Jul 20 13:04:51 GMT+05:00 2016"

    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    //This formats dates as following "Wed, 20 Jul 2016 08:04:51 +0000"
```

Now uptil here things work fine, the time with timezone GMT+05:00 is converted to standard UTC with GMT+00:00 that shown by +0000 in the formatted date

```
 Date setteledDate = dateFormat.parse(dateText);
```

Now Parsing the date as above gives the following date.
"Wed Jul 20 13:04:51 GMT+05:00 2016". The problem is this date is again in GMT+5
and the whole purpose of me getting current date formatting it and than parsing it is lost because the purpose was to get current date according to "UTC" (GMT+00:00).

Please help.

Comment: Which versions of Java are u using ?

Comment: I am using Java 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939967/java-simpledateformat-interpret-parse-string-as-utc

Answer (score 0):

Replace Z to z in SimpleDateFormat format.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();

//gives time as "Wed Jul 20 13:04:51 GMT+05:00 2016"

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
Log.e("date",dateText);
//output Wed, 20 Jul 2016 09:01:20 UTC

dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
Log.e("date",dateText);
//output  Wed, 20 Jul 2016 09:02:04 GMT+00:00
```

//update

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try {

            Date date = dateFormat.parse("Wed Jul 20 13:04:51 GMT+05:00 2016");
            Log.e("date",date.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: why are u changing the timezone ?

Comment: i am just give example of two timezone

Comment: Yes it does format according to the Timezone i have set. Once i have formatted currentDate with timezone UTC i get the correct date string, but when i parse it using the same simpleDateFormat object to convert this to Date object (having new timezone), it returns me the date i had at the very start (that is with the initial timezone).

Comment: set default time zone UTC or GMT than try